# how to find control inside a repeater on page_load?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i want to find a gridview control on page_load inside a repeater.How can i find it? please reply me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code dear because i think which @Waqas suggest you is the prefect one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) to access the ITemplate and find the control on there.

Here's an example:

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var data = e.Item.DataItem;
        var index = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        var gridView = e.Item.FindControl("gridView1") as GridView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
GridView gv = (GridView) repeater.FindControl("id-of-GridView);
```

Comment: i have searched on net and after that i got what i require and i have already paste it like answer. Thanks for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

```
     Repeater_bind()
        Dim count As Integer = rep_UnAssignComps.Items.Count
                        For j = 0 To count - 1
                    Dim grd As Gridview=  Dim rep_DataSimilarToBacthid As GridView = DirectCast(rep_UnAssignComps.Items(i).FindControl("rep_DataSimilarToBacthid"), GridView)

                Next
```